# sending post data with jquery on form submission

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

If I have this form which submits the post data to the page itself:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="name"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How will I be able to use JavaScript/jQuery to inject an additional POST data. This would be easier if I only submit the form via ajax using any of the functions like `$.post()`, `$.get()`, or `$.ajax()`. But what I want to do here is to submit the form not via ajax.

The additional data is in JavaScript. I'm thinking of just injecting a new hidden field into the DOM in which I will pass in the data so that it gets submitted with the form, but is there other way of doing it?

Please comment if you need more code/explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than using a submit button, use a regular button and control the submission via Javascript. In your javascript, you need to serialize the form and pass it as data along with anything else you want.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

       var extra_data = "This is more stuff to send";

       $('#submit').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "form.php",
             data: {'form': $("#my_form").serialize(), 'other': extra_data},
             success: function(msg) {
                alert("Form Submitted: " + msg);
             }
          });

       });

    });

</script>

<form id="my_form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say in the question body. I guess I'll just have to use ajax to submit the form then.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Hidden fields in your form. 2) AJAX. You pick, but personally I think the AJAX method is more robust and allows for more functionality such as form validation prior to submission.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#form_id').on('click','#submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_Ajax.php",
                data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<form method="post" id="form_id">
<input type="text" name="ime">
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

** get_ajax.php**

```
<?php
$ime = $_POST['ime'];

echo "Your name is $ime";
?>
```