# form is sended by jQuery but without data of fields

Tags: jquery, forms, post, onchange

```
$(function(){
    $('#sort').bind('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        $('#gosearch').attr('action', url);
        $("#gosearch").submit();
    });
});
```

With this code above choosed form (#gosearch) is sended but form was sended without any data inside the this form fields.. why? I tried a couple other ways, but any of them was works such as this, because they even want to send the form.

Please help.

Comment: Show your HTML. Make sure the fields are actually inside the form.

Comment: In first time when im on site and i dont have any data in POST, i fill the form and submit... all data was sended fine. On the page with results of sended form, the fields are now filled with data sended before... so now i have beside the SELECT with onchange function from code above.. the problem is... form was sended fine, but without any data, nevertheless fields of this form are not empty

Comment: The form must not be filled in correctly on the results page. You need to post the script that creates the results page so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Very weird is that when i send the formm, i can't view source of results page in my browser... when i push the CTRL +U comination for source instead i have message in browser "document has expired" .. why? form was sended thru the standard mode, not by jQuery

Comment: When you use `View Source`, it resends the request that generated the page, and this doesn't always work with form submissions. Instead, go into the Developer Tools and look at the Source tab, this shows the actual source of the current page.

Comment: http://codepad.org/40zDFrAq - this is it...

... when i explore the HTML source code of results page all looks fine... whe values are filled as well... the problem still is when i sumbit this form again via SELECT

Comment: I don't see a form or `gosearch` in the codepad.

Comment: http://codepad.org/uLAZIxBh - pleasse.. this is the rest of code responsible for the results page

Comment: I see code that does `if ($_POST)` and then binds a different `change` handler to `#sort`. Are you sure the right one is being used?

Comment: the #sort is ID of HTML SELECT element that must to act as a trigger to send the form again, so the results are now also sorted.. as you see if($_POST) is used to print the different jQuery code... other to page before form is sended, and second jQuery code after form is sended... yes.. in this place using the #sort is right one


the #sort SELECT is below from search fields elements, most bottom... on the pasted code this select is outside the form, but even is inside, the problem do not dissappear

Comment: The code looks OK, I'd have to see this live in the debugger to figure it out.

Comment: http://transg.x9d.pl/index.php?k=wolne_pojazdy -  bermar:bermar
only on wolne_pojazdy all works.. other are not ended... this one is for tests

Comment: ?k=wone-pojazdy NOT ?k=wolne_pojazdy !

Comment: When I change the Sort menu, it seems to be sending the form with all the values filled in.

Comment: http://transg.x9d.pl/index.php?k=wolne-pojazdy - bermar:bermar - THIS LINK IS CORRECT ... first please fille the search form, and send data.. after that on the result page the mysql_query will be printed... then if you use SELECT as a trigger to send form again.. the form trually was sended.. but without data.. so it seems becouse the mysql_query is not printed again... ... it means that other mysql query is used ..  part of script without "echo mysql_query" ... all You have in PHP code pasted before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in the search script:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
```

If you didn't click on the `search` button, this field is not set. Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['search']) || isset($_POST['sort'])) {
```

Comment: Yeap! You're RIGHT!
I use OR instead || ... but yes, all works fine now!

and in this case you write the name of sort SELECT field in english.. in code it is in polish :-)

Thanks a lot!!! Your eyes are BRAVE!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you proivde some JSfiddle or codepen of your code so that we can understand what exactly ur problem is.

If you want to send form data using AJAX see the below link

Possible duplicate of :

[sending post data with jquery on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863074/sending-post-data-with-jquery-on-form-submission)

Comment: he's not using AJAX, he's just submitting the form.

Comment: That't what I'm saying. I asked him to provide the jsfiddle of what he has done and if he wants to send the data using ajax, go through the given link because I don't know what exactly the code is.

Comment: Asking for additional information should be done in comments, not answers. When you get enough reputation (1 more point I think) you'll be able to comment on other people's questions.

Comment: Ya that's why I've posted the answer and suggested the link that might  be helpful to him